# Why does the player pass through the 3D tiles on tile map?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, tiles, tile

I have a tile map with 3D tiles which is facing according to the tile rule.
On each tile individually there is a box collider and they are marked as static objects for the occlusion culling.
My player has Rigidbody component and Box collider component as well, when with the player I'm turning and walking and trying to get through the tiles I'm succeeding, why?

Version of unity: 2021.3.20f1

[Link to the video to see how the issue looks](https://files.fm/f/cycvw765f)

I don't know what to try, I expect to fix this issue because it is unacceptable.

Comment: Hi, maybe you could show some code, or images of the inspector-setup of your objects. A video showing the current unintended effect would be nice as well. You could try asking on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ as well.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve]

Comment: Ok, I'll try to add some gif to visualize the issue

Answer (score 0):

Some possible reasons why it happened:

- Did you check if the player and tile layers are enabled in the Layer collision matrix? (Edit->Project Setting->Physics->Layer Collision Matrix)
- If it's marked try to check if the colliders "communicate" with each other by printing something on the screen.
- Check if both colliders don't have the "is Trigger" checkbox checked (both need to be unchecked).

Let me know if the problem is not solved and I will do my best to help.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
Yes, I tried and checked all you've suggested, everything is alright, the layers enabled, triggers are off and the collider "communicating" with each other.

I'll try to describe the problem more detailed - the player doesn't pass through the 3D tiles smoothly, it is followed by strange behavior like fast turns, insertions like being stuck and sometimes pushings upwards or to some other side.